# Merge three dataframes by two columns, keeping only the largest value in R

Tags: r

Lets say I have three dataframes:

```
df1 <- data.frame (first_column  = c("A", "B","C"),
                  second_column = c(5, 5, 5),
                  third_column = c(1, 1, 1)
                   )

df2 <- data.frame (first_column  = c("A", "B","E"),
                  second_column = c(1, 1, 5),
                  third_column = c(1, 1, 1)
                    )

df3 <- data.frame (first_column  = c("E", "F","G"),
                  second_column = c(1, 1, 5),
                  third_column = c(1, 1, 1)
                   )
```

I want to combine all of them based on first column, but if duplicated, keep only the row which has the largest value in the second_column.

So df1 + df2 + df3 =

```
first_column  second_column third_column
A             5             1
B             5             1
C             5             1
E             5             1
F             1             1
G             5             1
```

Any solution, even if requires two or more steps, is very welcome. (also, if value is equal in two column, keep any of them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dplyr` answer :

Bind dataframes in one combined dataframe, group by `first_column` and select the row which corresponding to max value of `second_column`.

```
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(mget(paste0('df', 1:3))) %>%
  group_by(first_column) %>%
  slice(which.max(second_column))

# first_column second_column third_column
#  <chr>        <chr>         <chr>       
#1 A            5             1           
#2 B            5             1           
#3 C            5             1           
#4 E            5             1           
#5 F            1             1           
#6 G            5             1
```

Answer (score 2):

a data.table approach:

```
library(data.table)

#convert dfs to data.tables
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)
setDT(df3)

# rbind them, order them decreasing by column_2 and get the first row for each column_1:
rbindlist(list(df1, df2, df3))[order(-second_column)][, .SD[1, ], by = first_column]

   first_column second_column third_column
1:            A             5            1
2:            B             5            1
3:            C             5            1
4:            E             5            1
5:            G             5            1
6:            F             1            1
```

Comment: A shorter version `setDT(rbindlist(list(df1,df2,df3)))[,lapply(.SD,max),first_column]`

Answer (score 2):

A simple base R option using `rbind` + `aggregate`

```
> aggregate(.~first_column, rbind(df1,df2,df3),max)
  first_column second_column third_column
1            A             5            1
2            B             5            1
3            C             5            1
4            E             5            1
5            F             1            1
6            G             5            1
```

Answer (score 1):

A similar `data.table` approach as @PavoDive's, but a bit more verbose:

```
# convert to data.tables
library(data.table)
setDT(df1); setDT(df2); setDT(df3)

# stack the three data.tables
df <- rbindlist(list(df1, df2, df3))

# aggregate by taking max
df[ , .(second_column = max(second_column),
        third_column = max(third_column)), by = .(first_column)]
```

Comment: In this case the third_column max is not needed right? If you only need to filter by the second column

Comment: A shorter version `setDT(rbindlist(list(df1,df2,df3)))[,lapply(.SD,max),first_column]`

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding - I always forget that `.SD` uses all non-by columns as default - a nice simplification!